# How to place multiple markers using lat long from JSON

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app I want to show the multiple marker using latitude and longitude from JSON but when I run the application it only shows one marker, other markers are not shown. Please help - here is my code:

```
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog; // class variable

        private void showProgressDialog(String title, String message)
        {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            progressDialog.setTitle(title); // set title 

            progressDialog.setMessage(message); // set message

            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

            progressDialog.show();
        } 

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showProgressDialog("Loading...", "Please wait for few seconds");
            //          dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().this);
            //          dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            //          dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            //  dialog.show();
            //  dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {


                //  Date a = new Date();
                //  a.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()-(60*60*1000));
                //  Log.e("onehourback",""+a);*/
                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("SingleIMEs");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //  Log.e("object",""+object);
                        /*try {
                        array.add(jarray.getJSONObject(i));

                        Log.e("array",""+array);
                        } catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }*/

                        for(int j=0; j < 1;j++)
                        {
                            latvalue=object.getString("Latitude");
                            longvalue=object.getString("Longitude");
                            latt=Double.parseDouble(latvalue);
                            lng=Double.parseDouble(longvalue);
                            Log.e("lat",""+latt);
                            Log.e("lon",""+lng);




                        }
                    }
                }
                //}
                return true;


                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }



        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            //dialog.cancel();
            if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            /*  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */
        }

    }
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) { 
        mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap(); 
        mMap.clear();

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latt,lng)).title("eee")); 
        Log.e("lat",""+latt);
        Log.e("lon",""+lng);

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 



        if (mMap != null) { 
            //setUpMap(); 
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() { 

                @Override 
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude()); 
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude())).title("WePOP")); 

                    //   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)).position( new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(datas.get("Lat")), Double.parseDouble(datas.get("Long"))))); 
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
                    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15)); 


                } 
            }); 

        } 
    } 
    @Override 
    public void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        mMapView.onResume(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onPause() { 
        super.onPause(); 
        mMapView.onPause(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onDestroy() { 
        mMapView.onDestroy(); 
        super.onDestroy(); 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're overwriting your latt and lng variables multiple times in this code:

```
for(int j=0; j < 1;j++)
{
    latvalue=object.getString("Latitude");
    longvalue=object.getString("Longitude");
    latt=Double.parseDouble(latvalue);
    lng=Double.parseDouble(longvalue);
    Log.e("lat",""+latt);
    Log.e("lon",""+lng);
}
```

I would suggest you create a List that holds some sort of object containing latt and lng information (something like List positions).
Then modify your code in setUpMapIfNeeded to cycle through all your LatLngs. Something like this:

```
for(LatLng latlng: positions) {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latlng.getLat(),latlng.getLng())).title("eee")); 
    Log.e("Added marker at lat: " + latlng.getLat() + ", lng: " + latlng.getLng());
}
```

Notice: It's been quite some time since i've used android and google maps, so the code i've written here probably isn't perfect - but the idea should be good :-)